# Using find() inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, find

The goal of my script is to print the outcome of netstart -a to a file called currservices.txt and then find services that have the words Network or Diagnostic in them. I created the loop to list all of the services started but don't quite understand how to use the find() function inside the loop to print out and services that have network or diagnostic in them.

```
import os 
my_command = "net start >I:\\temp\\mypythonfiles\\currservices.txt" 
os.system(my_command) 
value = "Network Diagnostic" 
my_path = "I:\\temp\\mypythonfiles\\currservices.txt" 
my_handle = open(my_path, "r") 
for line_of_text in my_handle: 
    print (line_of_text) 
    find_val = value.find("Network ") 
    print(find_val)
    my_handle.close()
```

1. Use the os module to execute "net start" while redirecting to a file called c:\temp\mypythonfiles\currservices.txt
2. Open the newly created file for reading
3. Create a loop to read each line from the file; within the loop:
    *Check each line using the find() method to list all of the started services related to the following: Network, Diagnostic
    *When found, print the service name

Answer (score 1):

First I don't think you need to write in a file, use subprocess.check_output instead :

```
import subprocess
# create and execute a subprocess and write its output into output (string) 
output = subprocess.check_output(["net", "start"])
```

Then I'm sure a regular expression would do the trick :

```
import re
regex = re.compile("Network|Diagnostic")
# split output (a raw multiline text) so you can iterate over lines
for p in output.splitlines():
    # test regex over current line
    if regex.match(p):
        print(p)
```

Comment: Agree. If this is a homework question, then you shouldn't have been asked to use find(), that's impractical. Use a regex instead